# Should I learn asp.NET MVC 3 without knowledge of MVC 1 or 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

FYI, I know asp.NET and planning to learn asp.NET MVC.  I heard that asp.NET MVC 3 has been released .  Should I learn MVC 3 right now? or should I start with MVC 1 or 2?

Thanks

Comment: Great resource for the "changes" to MVC 3 is Brad Wilsons blog posts: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt7-model-metadata.html

Comment: good question, i have same question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The core principles are all the same so learning MVC 3 would be the way to go. "Learning" 1 or 2 first would just mean you'd initial knowledge of the framework is already out of date. I always advice against learning older versions of frameworks because you often have to unlearn things when you get to the newest version of the framework

Comment: ok, but what if the company is using ASP.NET 2.0 (Visual Studio 2005)? are they able to install MVC 3?

Comment: See that's a different questions = ) MVC 3 requires .NET 4.0 (http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#software-requirements) so if you're stuck on .NET 2.0, then yeah you'll have to learn an older version. I thought MVC 2 required .NET 3.5, but I could be wrong.

Comment: oh no, even MVC 1.0 required asp.net 3.5! Unbelievable...so I may have to stick with non-mvc asp.net if I'm working with asp.net 2.0 :S
hmm...just wanna point out that a lot of companies are still using visual studio 2005...*sigh* too bad

Comment: Honestly the 2.0 to 3.5 upgrade is almost trivial. 1.1 to 2.0 was a b@&$%$ but otherwise I've found 2.0 -> 3.5/4.0 to require zero coding changes in my apps. It might be worth forking a branch, upgrading and then letting the company know Visual Web Developer 2010 is free = )

Answer (score 3):

Start with 3 - it's in iterative build upon 2 which was iterative upon 1.  If you learn 1 you will learn ways to do things that have been streamlined and improved in 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2):

You should learn version 3; it's a superset of the first two versions.
However, I'm not sure how much introductory material has been written for 3 yet.

Comment: +1 for the lack of introductory tutorials except in asp.net site and books.

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps "should" is a little subjective. But I can say, I am learning MVC 3 without having first learnt 1 or 2, and not having too hard a time with it.

[Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) is a must though ;-)

Comment: Don't look at the version of the Framework, think of it as the first version. It's very easy to get your head around once you dig into it.

PS: It's funny seeing Scott Guthrie's name in full. I know him as ScottGu :)

Answer (score 1):

You should get stuck into MVC3. The frameworks are iterations and improvements to the same basic programming paradigm.

Jon Galloway has re-coded his MvcMusicStore [example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1) for MVC3. All the tools you need are free, links are provided and you get to use NuGet!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should choose your own destiny. Try to learn MVC 3, with Razor View Engine also, you will see that you can. By the way,  it depends on the framework version you will use.